# c# HttpWebRequest not sending default credentials to proxy server

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, squid

I am using squid proxy server to authenticate the client before passing on the request to public network. 
I haven't set `HttpWebRequest.Proxy` object so I am assuming that the web request will take the default window credentials and pass on to the proxy server.

I have added an entry of the user to squid proxy as well, but I am getting the following error while making the request.:

```
(407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

In squid logs, I am getting this:

```
TCP_DENIED/407 3722 CONNECT
```

I have inserted the following block in App.config

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy
        usesystemdefault="true"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

To verify if there is discrepancy between the user credentials registered with squid and my windows user credentials. I tried opening a public website through browser which prompted for credentials as the request was passing through proxy server ( which I have set under Internet Options ), after entering windows credentials I was able to access that site.

Also, i checked through Fiddler ( a tool to check network traffic ) that the request to that proxy server didn't have Proxy-Authorization Header.

Can anybody please check and tell if something I have missed or I have made any mistake.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. The outgoing (CONNECT) HTTP request does not contain a Proxy-Authentication header at all (although it does have a Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive header). Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JamesBateson Unfortunately, I didn't. If you find any solution to this please do post because in our software release we have mentioned this functionality as 'not available' :(