# System.Net.WebClient - what's the best way of getting (non-default) proxy credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, proxies, http-status-code-407

I am writing a (WiX Burn) installer that needs to get licence information from our ASP.NET server. We are using the System.Net.WebClient to make this request.

Some of our customers are using authenticating proxies, which return 407 responses to our installer.

I initially tried passing on the default credentials as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603093/proxy-basic-authentication-in-c-http-407-error). However, on my machine and with the test proxy that I've set up, I'm getting the same issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734738/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-not-sending-default-credentials-to-proxy-server) where my default credentials simply aren't being picked up for some reason.

In any case, I imagine there will be cases where the proxy credentials are different from the default Windows credentials and the user will need to supply their proxy credentials manually.

I've seen a number of different options in Windows for this:

- Use the `CredUIPromptForCredentials` dialog, which Visual Studio seems to use.
- Use the more modern version [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134882/show-authentication-dialog-in-c-sharp-for-windows-vista-7).
- Use the [`InternetErrorDlg` dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204677/display-the-proxy-authentication-dialog-in-c-sharp)
- Forget about using the Windows dialogs and just deal with it in the installer UI.

What is the best way of doing this? Does it matter?

BONUS POINTS for helping with the issue of my default Windows credentials not being picked up by the `WebClient`!

Comment: Do you have to use WebClient?  What about HttpClient instead?

Comment: As we want the installer to work on vanilla Windows 7, we've chosen to use .NET 3.5. So we don't have HttpClient available.